# Setting up pebble sdk with jet brains cLion?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I would like to develop for the pebble using CLION (jetbrains c/c++ IDE). I am aware of cloud pebble , and would still like to use Clion. Could anybody tell me how to set it up so that :

1. I get auto complete for pebble sdk functions
2. When I click on run , the command `pebble build && install`
   is run .

Answer (score 3):

I use CLION to develop the C code for my Pebble apps.

To build/run I just have a terminal open within CLION, but I do like being able to refactor, have static analysis find errors, and to jump to the Pebble defs.

I created a new project based on the C source directory, and I've added all my source files to the CMakeLists.txt and the path to the Pebble include files and the generated resource file.  Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(src)
add_definitions(-DNOT_PEBBLE_BUILD)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        pblib/pblib.h ... main_menu_customizer.c main_menu_customizer.h string_values.c error_handler.c error_handler.h)

include_directories("~/Library/Application Support/Pebble SDK/SDKs/current/sdk-core/pebble/chalk/include" ../build/chalk/src)
add_executable(src ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

In  a general header file I also have these definitions to ensure that the generated resource file gets picked up, and that I don't get spurious errors for APP_LOG (might be fixed in the latest CLION):

```
#if NOT_PEBBLE_BUILD
#include <resource_ids.auto.h>
#undef APP_LOG // Clion doesn't support
#endif
```

Although not directly related to your question, you can also now [debug C code running in the emulator](https://developer.pebble.com/guides/tools-and-resources/pebble-tool/#emulator-interaction) using GDB, although not within CLION.  That would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add `CMakeLists.txt` files for the root project directory and `src`. Note that both files refer to the project name, in this case "`sd`" but it doesn't matter what you call it as long as it's the same in both files.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(sd)
SET(PEBBLE_FLAVOUR basalt)
SET(PEBBLE_SDK_VER 3.13.1)

SET(PEBBLE_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/.pebble-sdk/SDKs/${PEBBLE_SDK_VER}/sdk-core/pebble/${PEBBLE_FLAVOUR}/include")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PEBBLE_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR}")
# The generated files such as resource_ids are picked up from here:
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("build/${PEBBLE_FLAVOUR}")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("build/include")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/..)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
FILE(GLOB MainSources *.c)
ADD_LIBRARY(sd ${MainSources})
```

For inline documentation to work you will just need to install the latest CLion 2016.2 EAP.